# Get current keyboard layout using java

Tags: java, awtrobot

I wrote code that changes the layout language on the PC until English is selected, the language changes, the key combination is correct, but the loop continues forever

```
        InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();
        Locale curLocale = context.getLocale();
        
        while(!curLocale.equals(Locale.US)) {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            context = InputContext.getInstance();
            curLocale = context.getLocale();
        }
```

That is, the old layout value is written to curLocale

Comment: It seems, the AWT only updates its state if a window is open and it has the focus or receives the focus some time after the change.